# Rails - dynamically generating deeply nested attributes in forms

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, dynamic-forms

I haven't found a solution for my particular problem, or don't understand it enough to know where to look.

I have a nested form where I dynamically generate new objects as per Railscast 196/197. This works fine (in rails 3.0.9), except on a deeper level (3rd) with a mix of has_one and has_many. I am not sure if it's the necessary javascript modifications I don't understand, or associations, or initializing of nested attributes.

For simplicity, I translate my model so:
There is a tree that has_one trunk, and has_many apples. Each apple has_one core and has_many worms.

When I create a new tree, my Create form automatically displays the fields for the trunk, and fields for one apple with one core and two worms (I like my fruit populated and social...).

I can conditionally create an 'add' link for a trunk, just in case for some reason there isn't one.

I can dynamically create an add link for a new apple. However, when I do that, it is not automatically initialised with one core and two worms. I take it that is because it is generated via the javascript/helper, and not in the tree controller's 'new' method, as is the case for the form itself.

That's not so much the problem for the worms, as an apple can have zero worms, so it makes sense to generally have an 'add worm' link there anyway. However, an apple should have one and only one core, so I don't want an add-link for that, it should just be there.

Ideally, every "add apple" would initialise one core and two worms, though.

I don't know how to adapt the javascript/helper to initialise the nested attributes of apple (core and worms) when i add an apple.

I don't know, alternatively, how to initialise the apple object so that it has one core object initialised automatically.

I don't know, failing all that, how to access the core property in the apple(s) property of the tree controller through the view, so that I could do something similar as I do for the trunk - that is, "if for some reason trunk is not there, make a new one (or display an 'add' link to make a new one)" in the _form partial.

```
= if @tree.trunk.blank? 
  - @tree.trunk= Trunk.new -# or 'display add button'
= f.fields_for :trunk do |builder|
  = render 'shared/trunk_fields', :f => builder
```

--> this, but for one more level. If I go to _apple_fields partial and try something like @tree.apple/s.core, I get errors, the same if I go one further into the _core_fields partial and try to make core available to check for blank?. I can't find the correct syntax for being able to access one of the many apple's cores. And it wouldn't really be the ideal solution anyway.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. I am guessing the solution is really simple and I am just too new to all this to see it...